# Why is my withdraw method allowing me to take out more then has been deposited?

Tags: java

I have to write a ATM program for my computer science class. It works for the most part, apart from a couple logic problems within the programs itself. So far, from what I can tell, my ATM will deposit the correct amount of money that I tell it to however, when I withdraw money, it does not always withdraw the correct amount if I purposefully make an error (such as trying to take out an amount that is not a multiple of 20). I am also running into an issue where if I try to take out more money then is actually in the account, it will become a negative value, which I do not want to be allowed. I want it not to subtract the value that causes it to become negative and for it to prompt the user until a value less then or equivalent to the balance is able to be taken out. I am rather new to coding so please excuse my rather messy code. My error is probably around the else if statement where option == 3. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class aTMLauncher
{
    public static int options=0;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        aTMTester atm = new aTMTester();

        System.out.println("Login: \n(case sensitive)");
        System.out.print("Username > ");

        String usernameInput=input.nextLine();
        int count=4;
        while (!usernameInput.equals(aTMTester.getUsername()))
        {
            System.out.println("\nIncorrect input. Please try again. You have " + (count-1) + " trys remaining attempts.");
            System.out.println("Login: \n(case sensitive)");
            System.out.print("Username > ");
            count--;
            if(count==0)
            {
                System.out.println("No remain attempts, system will now exit");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            usernameInput = input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.print("Pin > ");
        int PINInput=input.nextInt();
        int count1=4;
        while (PINInput<aTMTester.getPIN() || PINInput>aTMTester.getPIN())
        {
            System.out.println("\nIncorrect input. Please try again. You have " + (count1-1) + " trys remaining");
            System.out.print("Pin > ");
            count1--;
            PINInput=input.nextInt();
            if(count1==0)
            {
                System.out.println("No remain attempts, system will now exit");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nWelcome, " + aTMTester.getUsername() +"!");

        while(PINInput==2468)
        {
            atm.main();
            options = input.nextInt();
            if (options==4)
            {
                atm.logout();
            }
            else if(options==2)
            {
                System.out.println("How much money would you like to deposit?");
                System.out.print("$ ");
                atm.deposit = input.nextInt();
                atm.balance+=atm.deposit;
                System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + atm.balance +"0");
            }
            else if(options==3)
            {
                System.out.println("How much money will you be withdrawing? \n(Only amounts divisible by 20 are accepted) \n$");
                atm.withdraw= input.nextInt();
                atm.balance-=atm.withdraw;
                if(atm.withdraw%20==0.0)
                {
                    System.out.println("You took out " +atm.withdraw);
                    System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + atm.balance);
                }
                while(atm.withdraw%20>0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid withdraw amount. Please retry.");
                    System.out.println("\nHow much money will you be withdrawing? \n(Only amounts divisible by 20 are accepted)");
                    atm.withdraw= input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("You took out " +atm.withdraw);
                    System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + atm.balance);
                }
                if(!(atm.balance>0.0))
                {
                    System.out.println("You are not allowed to take out more then you have in your account \n Please retry");
                    atm.withdraw= input.nextInt();
                }
            }
            else if(options==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Your account balance is $"+atm.balance+"0");
            }
        }
    }
}


public class aTMTester
{
    private static final String username = "David";
    private static final int PIN = 2468;
    public static int deposit, withdraw;
    public static double balance=0.00;
    private String menu;

    /*
     * Default constructor
     */

    public aTMTester()
    {
    }

    public static String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public static int getPIN()
    {
        return PIN;
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        System.out.println("\n+++++++++++Account: "+ username +"+++++++++++");
        System.out.println("1. Check Account Balance");
        System.out.println("2. Deposit Checks");
        System.out.println("3. Withdraw Money");
        System.out.println("4. Logout");

        System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to do next?\n");
    }

    public static void logout()
    {
        System.out.println("Thanks for usinging the David Vachlon Inc. ATM. We hope you expierence was fast and simple! Have a great day.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public static void deposit()
    {
        balance+=deposit;
    }

    public static void withdraw()
    {
        balance-=withdraw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions of the form "Here's my code, I don't know what's wrong" are off-topic here. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: If you want it not to subtract the withdrawal amount if it's too large, then I think the answer is to use an `if` to see if the withdrawal amount is too large, before you subtract.

Comment: Is this question better? Its more specific like it says in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do `atm.balance -= atm.withdraw;` **after** all checks was successfully passed. For instance, you may restructure your code as follows:

```
boolean ok = false;
while (!ok) {
    System.out.println("\nHow much money will you be withdrawing? \n(Only amounts divisible by 20 are accepted)");
    atm.withdraw = input.nextInt();
    if (atm.withdraw % 20 != 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid withdraw amount. Please retry.");
    } else if (atm.balance < atm.withdraw) {
        System.out.println("You are not allowed to take out more then you have in your account \n Please retry");
    } else if (atm.withdraw < 0) {
        // Probably you should not allow to withdraw a negative amount of money
    } else {
        ok = true;
    }
}
atm.balance -= atm.withdraw;
System.out.println("You took out " + atm.withdraw);
System.out.println("Your new balance is $" + atm.balance);
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped!